# Titanium appacelerator internationalization

Tags: webview, internationalization, titanium-mobile

I'm using titanium webviews to open an internal html page that I need to internationalize. This seems a rather basic need, but I can't seem to find the right documentation on how to accomplish it. This guide (https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Internationalization) points out how to use internationalization from app.js, but as I need to have it in my html I was wondering on the best way to do it. I was thinking on grabbing the onload event and populate the html with translated strings, but then, how do I obtain the html elements that should be translated? From my investigations it seems that I cannot use jQuery dom manipulation from within app.js..

Any help?

Comment: why don't you just open a pre-localized HTML page? So you grab a user locale and then open the page in user's language

Comment: Well, that doesn't seem the best approach to me. If I need to change something in the html, I will have several files to change the same thing.. but for now, it's the only option I have